# Enable Nuget packages restores using package.lock.json file without migrating csproj to SDK project style

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'm wondering if there is a solution to enable Nuget Packages restores using the packages.lock.json file without migrating the project to the project SDK style.

My second question is, can I enable this feature at the solution level?

As per this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/): I need to have a project with:

- NuGet.exe version 4.9 and above.
- Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 and
  above.
- .NET SDK version 2.1.500 and above.

Comment: Check Enabling the lock file and restore behavior with lock file from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#enabling-the-lock-file) and [Enable repeatable package restore using lock file](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-repeatable-package-restore-using-lock-file) maybe can help you.

Comment: No, it doesn't help, I have already tried to do this using the article you provided. I seem to be doable only on SDK-style projects.

Comment: NuGet documentation mentions that .NET SDK version 2.1.500 and above is required. That should only work in SDK-style projects.